# HTML/CSS - HTML and Body are much wider than content

Tags: html, css

I saw some related questions, but could not replicate anyone else's results. Here's my issue: I was developing a simple site template for practice. Everything was going great, but for some reason when I switch to my mobile view (currently set at 1188px just so I can diagnose problems), my body and HTMl extend way to the right of my CSS grid. No element that I can see in the inspector is overhanging.

Here's a link to a codepen containing my in-progress HTML and CSS. Just resize to about 1100 pixels to switch to the broken mobile view. https://codepen.io/BluntBSE/pen/NWxoWyj

HTML:

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #00FFF6;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #1A0AFF;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#6E105B, #40104E);
}


/*Set up CSS grid*/

#site_wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0px, 992px) minmax(36%, 992px) minmax(0px, 992px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px min-content min-content 60px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header header" ". left_pane title_pane right_pane ." ". left_pane content_pane right_pane ." "footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane"
}


/*Monitor Lines Overlay*/


/*
    
    body::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.20), transparent 2px, transparent 5px);
      pointer-events:none;
    
    }
    */


/*Make clickthrough work for IE 11*/


/*Heading and typograhy*/

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 5em;
}

a {
  color: #00FFF6;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #1A0AFF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1A0AFF, #1A0AFF 50%, #00FFF6 50%);
  background-position: 0 .9em;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* - Radial underline option
      background-image:radial-gradient(circle,  #00FFF6, #1A0AFF);
      background-position: 0 .9em;
      background-size: 100% 10px;
      background-repeat:repeat-x;
      text-decoration:none;
      */
}

.pane_button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #00FFF6;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  color: #1A0AFF;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px black;
}

.left_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  grid-area: left_pane;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  grid-area: title_pane;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: #00FFF6;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  >* {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

.title_cell {
  margin: 60px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.blog_title {
  display: inline;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1A0AFF, #1A0AFF 50%, #00FFF6 50%);
  background-position: 0 .9em;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.blog_path {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.path_cell {
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.content_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  grid-area: content_pane;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #00FFF6;
}

.right_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  grid-area: right_pane;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  grid-area: footer_pane;
}

.right_pane_metawrapper {
  max-width: 320px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}


/*Interactives, Hovers, etc.*/

a:hover {
  color: #1A0AFF;
  background-color: #00FFF6;
  background-image: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1188px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1188px) {
  .pane_button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    ;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:1188px) {
  #site_wrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px min-content min-content min-content min-content 60px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "left_pane left_pane left_pane" "title_pane title_pane title_pane" "right_pane right_pane right_pane" "content_pane content_pane content_pane" "footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane"
  }
  .left_pane {}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Nostromo Theme</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="site_wrap">

    <div class="header">
      <h1>Nostromo — Advanced Hypertext Processor</h1>
      <H1>Search</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="left_pane">
      <ul>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="title_pane">
      <span class="title_cell">
              <h1 class="blog_title">A Treatise on Ethics Most Profound Such that this title becomes super goddamn long</h1>
            </br>
          </span>
      <span class="path_cell">
              <span class="blog_path">C:\Users\BluntBSE\AFatTreatise.txt</span>
      </span>
      </span>

    </div>
    <div class="content_pane">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form,
        accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right_pane">
      <ul class="right_pane_metawrapper">
        <li class="metainfo">Author: Patrick Swan</li>
        <li class="metainfo">Category:Blog</li>
        <li class="metainfo">Tags: Nostromo</li>
        <li class="metainfo">Date: 01/01/2020</li>
        <li class="metainfo">Notes: This is a terrible theme designed to hurt you.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_pane">
      <h1>FOOTER</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm really tearing my hair out over this one. Overflow-x:hidden; didn't have any effect on body, so I am completely at a loss. I assume it's something wrong with my media query since that's when it breaks, but I can't tell what it is.

[Oversized body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2q1M.png)

Comment: If you want better mobile view, try adding viewport. Read more here: https://w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have included   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to my <head>, but it does not appear to have made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in the `grid-template-columns` definition in the media query. Instead of using `min-content`, you can use `minmax(auto, 1fr)`. Also, when you are coding in codepen:

1. Do not give `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. Put only the content of the body in the editor.
2. Everytime you should analyse your HTML or CSS in codepen. There were lots of small mistakes here and there.

Also, when you are using media query, the thumb rule is to include - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and put all the media queries at one place.

Please, see the edited code below. I have changed the mobile width to `800px`.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: "VT323", monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #00fff6;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #1a0aff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#6e105b, #40104e);
}

/*Set up CSS grid*/

#site_wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    1fr minmax(auto, 1fr) 4fr minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px min-content min-content 60px;

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header"
    ". left_pane title_pane right_pane ."
    ". left_pane content_pane right_pane ."
    "footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane";
}

/*Monitor Lines Overlay*/

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    transparent 2px,
    transparent 5px
  );
  pointer-events: none;
}
*/

/*Make clickthrough work for IE 11*/


/*Heading and typograhy*/
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 5em;
}

a {
  color: #00fff6;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #1a0aff;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #1a0aff,
    #1a0aff 50%,
    #00fff6 50%
  );
  background-position: 0 0.9em;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;

  /* - Radial underline option
  background-image:radial-gradient(circle,  #00FFF6, #1A0AFF);
  background-position: 0 .9em;
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  text-decoration:none;
  */
}

.pane_button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #00fff6;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  color: #1a0aff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px black;
}

.left_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  grid-area: left_pane;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  grid-area: title_pane;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: #00fff6;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  > * {
    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

.title_cell {
  margin: 60px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.blog_title {
  display: inline;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #1a0aff,
    #1a0aff 50%,
    #00fff6 50%
  );
  background-position: 0 0.9em;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.blog_path {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.path_cell {
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.content_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  grid-area: content_pane;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #00fff6;
}
.right_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  grid-area: right_pane;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer_pane {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  grid-area: footer_pane;
}

.right_pane_metawrapper {
  max-width: 320px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

/*Interactives, Hovers, etc.*/

a:hover {
  color: #1a0aff;
  background-color: #00fff6;
  background-image: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  .pane_button {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
    #site_wrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr) minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-rows:
      60px
      min-content
      min-content
      min-content
      min-content
      60px;

    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "left_pane left_pane left_pane"
      "title_pane title_pane title_pane"
      "right_pane right_pane right_pane"
      "content_pane content_pane content_pane"
      "footer_pane footer_pane footer_pane";
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="site_wrap">

        <div class="header">
            <h1>Nostromo — Advanced Hypertext Processor</h1>
            <h1>Search</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="left_pane">
         <ul>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="pane_button"><a class="pane_button" href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="title_pane">
          <span class="title_cell">
          <h1 class="blog_title">A Treatise on Ethics Most Profound Such that this title becomes super goddamn long</h1>
        <br>
      </span>
          <span class="path_cell">
          <span class="blog_path">C:\Users\BluntBSE\AFatTreatise.txt</span>
        </span>

        </div>
        <div class="content_pane">
          <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right_pane">
          <ul class="right_pane_metawrapper">
            <li class="metainfo">Author: Patrick Swan</li>
            <li class="metainfo">Category:Blog</li>
            <li class="metainfo">Tags: Nostromo</li>
            <li class="metainfo">Date: 01/01/2020</li>
            <li class="metainfo">Notes: This is a terrible theme designed to hurt you.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_pane">
          <h1>FOOTER</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding CodePen, and thank you very much for the clarification on CSS Grid. I clearly misinterpreted how min-content works, and your edit got me to the expected behavior I was looking for. I cannot express my gratitude enough!

Comment: Happy that it helped you..!! Good luck.. Could you please accept my answer here. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Done! I am still very new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thankyou..!! No worries, you will learn eventually..!!